# Django Template Variable Failing as href Value

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created a Django template which serves as an email template for my app. Upon certain actions, a celery task sends an email from this template using Sendgrid. Previously I hard-coded the URLs but now I need them to be dynamic. I am passing the url string as a variable called profile_url. I know that the URL is formatted correctly because I am printing it before calling the send_mail() function. If I use the value like so it works:

```
<p>{{ profile_url }}</p>
```

However, when I use it as an href value the link renders unclickable:

```
<a
  href="{{ profile_url }}"
  target="_blank"
  style="
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    "
>Go to your profile</a>
```

If anyone can assist me or at least point me in the right direction here I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a
  href="{{ modelname.profile_url }}"
  target="_blank"
  style="
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: block;
    "
>Go to your profile</a>
```

you have to called field with its  model name and i also assume that this profile_url is in models.URLField still getting error add your model

Comment: I've never used models.URLField. This is an interesting approach but I don't see any reason why this URL needs to be explicitly connected to a model. I'd really just like to use the url exactly as it is passed to the send_confirmation_mail function if possible.

Comment: @AlecD'Alelio django provide us type field depending on our need like Char Field Image Field so i assume you are saving url in charfield  which is only for charactes string no you can save that url in that but if you want to load that url with href tag it will not consider as url it will considered as a string so must have to use that field which is applicable to that type

Comment: I appreciate the tip @Shreyash! However this url is not saved anywhere in my db and has no relation to any of my models. It is simply a parameter of the send_mail() function which is used to template the email. Thus I'm not sure how I could use a model field to achieve this. You're right that the issue probably has to do with the fact that the URL is a string and therefore maybe the Django template doesn't know how to handle it.